# Salesforce to Salesforce integration

Tags: integration

Kindly share a link or method for Salesforce to Salesforce integration to be done with coding and not like the method explained in [https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce][1]

@future Trigger-

```
trigger HandleLeadUpdate on Lead (after update) {   
Map<ID, Lead> oldMap =  new Map<ID, Lead>(Trigger.old);  
List<Id> LdIds = new List<Id>();   
for (Lead ld: Trigger.new) {
    if (ld.Status == 'Open - Not Contacted' &&  oldMap.get(ld.Id).Status != 'Open - Not Contacted'){
        LdIds.add(ld.Id);
    }
}   
if (LdIds.size() > 0) {
    Integration.postOrder(LdIds);
 }
}
```

Class-

```
public class Integration {



public class ExternalOrder {
    public String id {get; set;}
    public String Name {get; set;}

}

@future (callout=true) 
public static void postOrder(List<Id> LdIds) {


    JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);

    gen.writeStartArray();

    for (Id LdId : LdIds) {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('id', LdId);
        gen.writeEndObject();            
    }

    gen.writeEndArray();

    String jsonOrders = gen.getAsString();

    System.debug('jsonOrders: ' + jsonOrders);


    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

    req.setMethod('POST');

    req.setEndpoint('https://ap2.salesforce.com/001/e?retURL=%2F001%2Fo');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setBody(jsonOrders);    

    Http http = new Http();

    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

    System.debug('Fulfillment service returned '+ res.getBody());


    if (res.getStatusCode() != 200) {
        System.debug('Error from ' + req.getEndpoint() + ' : ' +
          res.getStatusCode() + ' ' + res.getStatus());
    }

    else {

        List<Lead> Lds = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :LdIds];

        List<ExternalOrder> orders = (List<ExternalOrder>)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),
            List<ExternalOrder>.class);

        Map<Id, Lead> LdMap = new Map<Id, Lead>(Lds);

        for ( ExternalOrder order : orders ) {
          Lead Ld = LdMap.get(order.id);
          Ld.Name = String.valueOf(order.Name);
        }

        update Lds;
    }      
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can  you let me know the purpose of this integration? Do you want to hit any particular class ?

Comment: I have done an integration between DEV and QA sandbox because I wanted to use a particular class of QA to return some data. Do you have similar requirement?

Comment: I want to integrate Lead between two different DEV orgs

Comment: Please elaborate the requirement. One line is not enough.

Comment: I need to share Lead's data with another DEV org such that if a field is updated, created or deleted, same should reflect the same in other org. And I need to achieve this by coding.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Since you need to share lead data with different org on any DML action, write a trigger on Lead that will call a method in a class. This method should be annotated with @futute as we need to make callouts. All the operations will be performed in this class method asynchronously.
2. The next step would be login into the target org because you won't be able to access the data until you login. For this, you need to create a "Connected App" in the target org. Upon creation, you will be provided with Consumer Key and Consumer secret. [Click here to know more about Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_create.htm)
3. After the app is created you can check this app by visiting Set up -> Apps -> Connected Apps.
4. Now you need to write a class in the target org that will be hit by the request. As a result this class will get whatever request is coming, deserialize the request into Lead object and insert/update the same in the target org. To achieve this you will have to expose this class as [@RestResource](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/Content/apex_rest_1.htm) . This will ensure this class is available to be hit by the incoming request. "urlmapping" provides you the endpoint to activate this class.
5. Now coming to the request part, first we need to login. For that we will require - Username, Password, Security token, Consumer key, Consumer secret of target org. With the help of above parameter, you will be able to login to the org.

   ```
       `reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret+'&username='+username+'&password='+password+stoken;
        Http ht = new Http();
        HttpRequest requ = new HttpRequest();
        requ.setBody(reqbody);
        requ.setMethod('POST');
        requ.setEndpoint(settings.EndPoint_OAuth2_QA__c);`
   ```
6. The output can be captured in HttpResponse. You can debug this to check if the login was a success.
7. After the login is a success you need to serialize the Lead records in context as JSON, and then pass the same using Http methods. This will form the request body and the same can be deserialized in the target org and then DML actions can be performed on them.

You may face challenges if you haven't worked on webservices yet. If so, I would recommend you to go through REST Api, JSON, Http class in Salesforce. Please do let me know if you have further concerns.

Comment: Thanks alot... I will try it and update about the same...

Comment: Could you help me with a sample code for trigger and the class required here.

Comment: I'm stuck at 5th point. How to check the same?

Comment: Can you show me what have you written till now? I can make modifications.

Comment: I have added the code with the main question. This is what I've done so far and not sure how to proceed with 5th point.

Comment: I am checking. Will get back to u.